# Cannot pass 'cxnDb' as a ref or out argument because it is a 'using variable'

Tags: c#, vb.net

Hi I converted code from VB.NET to C#. I converted using Developer Fusion. I had many errors initially and I cleared out all those errors except this. This is the VB.net code :

```
   If cxnDb.State = ConnectionState.Open Then

   If AppSettings("skipCredits") Is Nothing Then

   Console.WriteLine("CREDITS")

   chargeCredits(cxnDb)

   Console.WriteLine()

   End If
```

And this is the equivalent C# code I have :

```
     if (cxnDb.State == ConnectionState.Open)
      {
     if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["skipCredits"] == null)
      {
      Console.WriteLine("CREDITS");
      chargeCredits( ref cxnDb);
      Console.WriteLine();
      }
```

But when I try to build my solution I am getting :

**Cannot pass 'cxnDb' as a ref or out argument because it is a 'using variable'** error.

If I remove ref keyword that is `chargeCredits(cxnDb);` I am getting it must be passed with ref keyword.

Can someone help me in this?

**Update:** 
My C# chargeCredits method implementation is as follows :

```
     private static void chargeCredits( SqlConnection cxnFinanceDb)
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdCredits = cxnDb.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmdCredits.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmdCredits.CommandText = "bill_Credits";
            cmdCredits.CommandTimeout = 60;

            try
            {
                cmdCredits.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException exDetail)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" + cmdCredits.SqlException :: " + exDetail.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception exDetail)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" + cmdCredits.Exception :: " + exDetail.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                cmdCredits.Dispose();
            }
        }
         }
```

Here I removed ref in my method to make it work.

Comment: Don't use `ref`. You have no need for it.

Comment: @Arran As I said before if I don't use ref I am getting it should be passed with ref error.

Comment: How is chargeCredits structured? What's the purpose of `ref` in it? Chances are it can be rewritten in VB.NET, so that `ref` is no longer necessary.

Comment: Well remove the `ref` keyword from your `chargeCredits` method too. Post the contents of the `chargeCredists` method if you are unsure on what to remove.

Comment: @Arran Thanks it worked.I removed ref from that method, now its working.How can i accept this as answer here ?

Comment: @Raj, great! I have added it as an answer, accept it when you can.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`ref` is unneeded here. I am unsure on where you got that from, but it is not necessary in your case.

So your easiest solution is to just remove it.

This means removing it from here:

```
chargeCredits( ref cxnDb);
```

and from your `chargeCredits` method too. I assume it's something like:

```
public void chargeCredits(ref SqlConnection cxnDB)
```

Remove it from there too.

Comment: Without knowing what that method does, how can you know that it doesn't need to pass the object by reference?  It might rely on that behavior.  (I'd *hope* not, but without seeing it's implementation, we can't know.)  At the very least it may mean a more involved refactor of that other method.

Comment: @servy In my VB.NET code we are using byref like this Private Sub chargeCredits(ByRef cxnDb As SqlConnection), so i used ref here.but it was giving me error.But after removing ref from my method as **Arran** told it is not showing any error. hope it works as it should be.

Comment: @Raj Sure, it'll compile, but depending on how the method is implemented it may or may not *work*.  It's possible that the method that no reason to mark the parameter as `ref` to begin with, and that that was the error, but it's equally possible that the variable itself is modified within the method, and if it is, the method is now buggy.  He can't know if that's the case or not, since you haven't shown the implementation.  At the very least, a responsible answer would indicate the possibility and ensure that you knew how to ensure that this is the only change that is needed.

Comment: @Servy I updated my post.I add my chargeCredits method implementation.Can you have a look into that please??

Comment: @Raj The method doesn't use the parameter *at all*.  Just remove it entirely if that's the case.

Comment: This fixes the problem, sure, but doesn't explain the source of the error. The OP should understand what's actually going on with that `using` block.